# How to format as Text using Text-To-Columns

Tags: excel, vba

This code works using text to columns to separate column A into as many columns as I need, but I cannot figure out a way to make it do this with all columns outputted into text format.

```
Sub TxT_to_Columns()
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").TextToColumns _
    Destination:=Range("A1"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
    Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, _
    Space:=False, _
    Other:=True, _
    OtherChar:="|"
End Sub
```

How can I do the same thing but output all columns to text format?

Thank you,

Comment: Use `FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2)`. But you can format using `TextToComun` only one column at a time.

Comment: @FaneDuru no, you can do multiple using an array of arrays like my answer.  That will format three columns not just one.

Comment: @Scott Craner: Good to know... Thanks! When I tried to manually use TextToColumn on multiple rows, a message saying something like that "Microsoft Excel can convert only one column at a time." I never imagined that VBA can do that...

Comment: @FaneDuru you can only choose one column of data to split, but you can format multiple columns of the output.

Comment: @Scott Craner: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I used for defining of `FieldInfo` your first array of arrays in order to format columns A:C as Text, but  only column A:A is formatted in this way... The other two are properly formatted only when they correspond to `Array(1, 2)`. I will keep trying. I used to had sicked on the brain that only a column can be formatted using of TextToColumn and now I was exciting to find out that it is possible, but I cannot do it... Now, it is late in my country, but I will test again tomorrow...

Comment: Again you can only have one column as input.  So if A1 has `001|002|003` and you want to split that on the `|` and have all three outputs as text then you would use the FieldInfo string below.

Comment: @Scott Craner: It is obvious I firstly did not understand what the question asked... Then, I misunderstood your explanation, which were very clear. I tried a comment before seeing what you said and then I didn't observed it. Making the long story shorter, you were right and I was (wrongly) speaking about something else... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use FieldInfo:

```
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2)),
```

FieldInfo uses an array of arrays: `Array(Array(Column,Type),...)`

You can get the types from here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolumndatatype

If you know you want to do all the columns then you can pre fill an variant arr variable:

```
Sub TxT_to_Columns()
    Dim arr(1 To 10) As Variant

    arr(1) = Array(1, 2)
    arr(2) = Array(2, 2)
    arr(3) = Array(3, 2)
    arr(4) = Array(4, 2)
    arr(5) = Array(5, 2)
    arr(6) = Array(6, 2)
    arr(7) = Array(7, 2)
    arr(8) = Array(8, 2)
    arr(9) = Array(9, 2)
    arr(10) = Array(10, 2)


    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").TextToColumns _
        Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:="|", _
        FieldInfo:=arr
End Sub
```

Comment: Will this work if the text is being converted into more than 10 columns?  I see you have 10 arrays defined in your suggested code.

Comment: Just creat a larger array

Comment: @Sabatino Ognibene: You can automatically build the array of arrays. Use `Redim` after array declaration and... You will not understand here, I am afraid. I will try a new answer to clarify this aspect, but **all the credit must go to Scott Craner**!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, **all the credit must go to Scott Craner!**

I will only show a shorter way of arrays building, as response at what @Sabatino Ognibene asked lately. I am sure that Scott knew that, but he wanted to present the array building in a way able to easily be understood.

```
Dim arr() As Variant, i As Long, nrCol As Long
    nrCol = 12 'the number of columns you need to result
    ReDim arr(1 To nrCol) As Variant
    For i = 1 To nrCol
      arr(i) = Array(i, 2) '2 will be used for `Text` formatting.
    Next
```